# Linear interpolation between values

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, interpolation

I have a table *t* with x and y values spaced out between every 10 integers of x (`value` column), for example:

```
   value   -20   -10     0    24    40    55
1    100 41700 41700 41700 41700 41800 41700
2     90 40200 40600 40700 40800 40800 40800
3     80 39200 39700 39800 40000 40000 39900
4     70 38200 38800 38800 39000 39100 39000
5     60 37200 37800 37900 38000 38200 38200
6     50 36200 36700 36900 37000 37000 37000
7     40 35400 35900 36200 36300 36300 36400
8     30 34600 35300 35600 35800 35800 35900
9     20 33700 34600 34800 35200 35100 35100
10    10 31600 33700 33800 34000 33900 33900
11     0 30000 30000 26500 30700 30100 30100
```

Right now, the table is 11 rows x 7 columns.  My goal is to interpolate values linearly in all 6 columns for **each integer between 0 and 100** so that the table in the end is 101 rows x 7 columns.

I am able to interpolate each column separately using the following method:

```
x <- t$value
y <- t$`-20`
plot(x, y, main = "-20 mv", xlab = "soc", ylab = "temp", pch = 20)
points(approx(x, y, xout = 0:100), col ="blue", pch = 1)
```

[image]

Can anywone suggest a faster method with `dplyr` or `data.table` or base R with a few commands that will apply this to the entire table?

The data:

```
dput(t)
structure(list(value = c(100L, 90L, 80L, 70L, 60L, 50L, 40L, 
30L, 20L, 10L, 0L), `-20` = c(41700L, 40200L, 39200L, 38200L, 
37200L, 36200L, 35400L, 34600L, 33700L, 31600L, 30000L), `-10` = c(41700L, 
40600L, 39700L, 38800L, 37800L, 36700L, 35900L, 35300L, 34600L, 
33700L, 30000L), `0` = c(41700L, 40700L, 39800L, 38800L, 37900L, 
36900L, 36200L, 35600L, 34800L, 33800L, 26500L), `24` = c(41700L, 
40800L, 40000L, 39000L, 38000L, 37000L, 36300L, 35800L, 35200L, 
34000L, 30700L), `40` = c(41800L, 40800L, 40000L, 39100L, 38200L, 
37000L, 36300L, 35800L, 35100L, 33900L, 30100L), `55` = c(41700L, 
40800L, 39900L, 39000L, 38200L, 37000L, 36400L, 35900L, 35100L, 
33900L, 30100L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L
))
```

Comment: do you only want for plotting reaons ?

Comment: no, I just need to create a table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `dplyr` you can do:

```
library(dplyr)

t %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~approx(value, ., xout=0:100)$y))
```

> ```
>     value   -20   -10     0    24    40    55
> 1       0 30000 30000 26500 30700 30100 30100
> 2       1 30160 30370 27230 31030 30480 30480
> 3       2 30320 30740 27960 31360 30860 30860
> 4       3 30480 31110 28690 31690 31240 31240
> 5       4 30640 31480 29420 32020 31620 31620
> ...
> 95     94 40800 41040 41100 41160 41200 41160
> 96     95 40950 41150 41200 41250 41300 41250
> 97     96 41100 41260 41300 41340 41400 41340
> 98     97 41250 41370 41400 41430 41500 41430
> 99     98 41400 41480 41500 41520 41600 41520
> 100    99 41550 41590 41600 41610 41700 41610
> 101   100 41700 41700 41700 41700 41800 41700
> ```

Or in base R:

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(t, function(y) {approx(t$value, y, xout=0:100)$y}))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `data.table` method that is similar in principal to the `dplyr` method:

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(t)
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(y) approx(value, y, xout = 0:100)[['y']])]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a kind of manual R base solution:

```
sapply(df[,-1],function(col){
  c(col[1],lapply(c(diff(col))/10,function(x) x*1:10) %>% 
    unlist() + rep(col[-11],each = 10) )
})
```

not totally sure it is faster though

```
       -20   -10     0    24    40    55
  [1,] 41700 41700 41700 41700 41800 41700
  [2,] 41550 41590 41600 41610 41700 41610
  [3,] 41400 41480 41500 41520 41600 41520
  [4,] 41250 41370 41400 41430 41500 41430
  [5,] 41100 41260 41300 41340 41400 41340
  [6,] 40950 41150 41200 41250 41300 41250
  [7,] 40800 41040 41100 41160 41200 41160
  [8,] 40650 40930 41000 41070 41100 41070
  [9,] 40500 40820 40900 40980 41000 40980
 [10,] 40350 40710 40800 40890 40900 40890
 [11,] 40200 40600 40700 40800 40800 40800
 [12,] 40100 40510 40610 40720 40720 40710
....
 [90,] 31810 33790 33900 34120 34020 34020
 [91,] 31600 33700 33800 34000 33900 33900
 [92,] 31440 33330 33070 33670 33520 33520
 [93,] 31280 32960 32340 33340 33140 33140
 [94,] 31120 32590 31610 33010 32760 32760
 [95,] 30960 32220 30880 32680 32380 32380
 [96,] 30800 31850 30150 32350 32000 32000
 [97,] 30640 31480 29420 32020 31620 31620
 [98,] 30480 31110 28690 31690 31240 31240
 [99,] 30320 30740 27960 31360 30860 30860
[100,] 30160 30370 27230 31030 30480 30480
[101,] 30000 30000 26500 30700 30100 30100
```

Comment: `do.call(cbind, lapply(t, function(y) {approx(t$value, y, xout=0:100)$y}))`

Comment: @eipi10 yes, nice one, but using approx again. I dont have time for the benchmark, but I would love to see one.